# Does p5.js support steering wheel and gas pedal input and how to read input?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, logitech

I am writing a web based race car game using JavaScript and p5.js on a Mac.

Does p5.js or Javascript accept steering wheel device input?
And how how would you read input from a steering wheel device and gas pedal device in P5.js?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not up to `p5.js` - they're bound by the browser-vendors. Such-as-it-is, [Chromium-based browsers do support _WebHID_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebHID_API), so if `p5.js` doesn't support it, you should be able to hack-on support yourself.